# A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013

Tags: windows-10, office365, sharepoint

We keep receiving the following message on our computer, every minute or so. It seems associated with a locally synced SharePoint document library. Here is the message:

[image: Something went wrong...]

> Something went wrong. We couldn't start your program. Please try
>   starting it again. If it won't start, try repairing Office from
>   'Programs and Features' in the Control Panel. [You can go online to
>   find more help.](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Try-these-solutions-to-fix-your-Office-error-54554bb8-aa94-43c7-a685-408dd9868c0b?NS=OCSAC2RCLICKTORUN&Version=15&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&HelpId=0x80004005-0x8b10072a-&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

What we have tried:

1. Restart the program.
2. Restart the computer.
3. Repair Office from 'Programs and Features.' We did this for both Microsoft Office 365 and Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus, because both are installed.)
4. Uninstall both versions of Office.
5. Reinstall Office 365 ProPlus.

In the Event Viewer, we see the following messages:

> The server {E844CD23-864D-4921-B18B-ED60A150E112} did not register
>   with DCOM within the required timeout.

--

> A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The
>   internal error state is 10013.

The latter message, about the SSL client, appears about 50 times. We have looked at [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aaced205-b0ec-4874-b440-8075dd74d8df/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-an-ssl-client-credential-the-internal-error-state-is-10013?forum=exchangesvradmin). It suggests that we enable `System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing`, though we are not sure whether that will be necessary or not.

Comment: Have you uninstalled Office then installed it again?  A repair function is not identical to, removing a program and then  installing it.  What version of Office, based on the error, it appears your using Office 365 without the ability to connect Microsoft's servers.

Comment: Please try doing that.  Update your question the relevant information.  "fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013." this error indicates a certificate store problem on your machine.

Comment: @Ramhound If it's an SSL client credential problem, then will uninstalling and reinstalling Office resolve that, or will we have to take further measures?

Comment: Only one way to find out

Comment: @Ramhound What do you think about our `System cryptography FIPS` setting being disabled? Does it seem likely that we need to have it enabled? I know very little about cryptography.

Comment: **The default is disabled.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked was to uninstall and reinstall Office.

Comment: Please consider marking this the accepted answer if it indeed was the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution was [posted](https://forums.iis.net/t/1233122.aspx) on the Microsoft IIS forum:

> According to the event log, the issue is related to Schannel. Please
>   try the following steps:
>
> 1. In Control Panel, click Administrative Tools, and then double-click Local Security Policy.
> 2. In Local Security Settings, expand Local Policies, and then click Security Options.
> 3. Under Policy in the right pane, double-click System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing,
>      and then click Enabled.
> 4. Run gpupdate /force
>
> If it doesn’t work, please go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA
>   and grant "Network Services" Read permission to "MachineKeys" folder.
>   Then restart server to have a try.

Comment: I quote an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1370333/201818) (by [Jeff](https://superuser.com/users/957860/jeff)) which I find helpful as a comment for this answer (he didn't have enough reputation to write this as a comment): The only problem with enabling FIPS compliance is that if you have hardened the server or pc to PCI compliance, it will turn back on TLS1.0, which violates PCI.