# A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013

Tags: windows-10

Similar to [A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013](https://superuser.com/questions/1023771/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-an-ssl-client-credential-the-internal-err)

Windows 10 1909

My System event log is 90% filled with

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Schannel
Date:          29/01/2021 12:40:33
Event ID:      36871
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      removed
Description:
A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Schannel" Guid="{1f678132-5938-4686-9fdc-c8ff68f15c85}" />
    <EventID>36871</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-01-29T12:40:33.338438000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>137396</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{9e0531d4-f4e8-0002-5932-059ee8f4d601}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="1236" ThreadID="5536" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>removed</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="Type">client</Data>
    <Data Name="ErrorState">10013</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

It doesn't appear to be the same issue as the related topic mentioned above, as my Office applications are working just fine. A colleague suggested perhaps a browser extension is to blame, but I'm not so sure.

Process ID 1236 is `lsass.exe`, and Thread ID 5536 appears to be a wait queue.

[image]

What can I do to resolve this, such that my system event log isn't full of these errors? Or do I just ignore it?

Note: I tried the change suggested in [the similar](https://superuser.com/questions/1023771/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-an-ssl-client-credential-the-internal-err) question, but the issue persists.

Comment: Is this machine connected to an AD domain by chance?

Comment: Yes, it's on a corporate domain.

Comment: Have you contacted your IT Administrator.  Any solution will that I cpu offer required Administrator permissions on the domain.